# undefined method for nil:NilClass linking to profiles

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, null

I'm trying to link from the current user page to other users profile page and When i click on someone's name i get the following error`: undefined method`profile_photo' for nil:NilClass`

So i have this in my show view :

```
<%- model_class = Account -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.titleize %></h1>
</div>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dd><%= image_tag @account.profile_photo.url %></dd>
   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.name %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:gender) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.gender %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:age) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.age %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name("Date Of Birth") %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= (@account.year_Of_Birth.to_s) +"/"+(@account.month_Of_Birth.to_s)+"/"+(@account.day_Of_Birth.to_s)  %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:country) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.country %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:favorite_Sport) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @account.favorite_Sport %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:account_id) %>:</strong></dt>

</dl>
```

This on my page view :

...

```
 <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to account.name, account %></td>
```

...

and this is on my controller :
...

```
def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end
```

...

Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't look like `@account` is being found - can you check on your controller that `@account` is being set?

Comment: as I said on the post i put this on the controller :
def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end
By the way, account is a devise model

Comment: where do you set the `@accounts` (plural)` ?

Comment: I'm not, I'm a begginer sorry

Comment: That could be an issue, set the `@accounts` in your show action: `@accounts = Account.all` see if it resolves the issue

Comment: Typically your controller would have 
     `def show
        @account = Account.find(params[:id])
     end`

Comment: And `def index @accounts = Account.all end`

Comment: You might want to post your `routes.rb` file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is related to link_to tag, In this tag, second parameter is show action path.
But you have passed object.
Please check the routes for your respective controller & action

Use command : rake routes

And than change the second parameter to routes_path(account.id)

Change routes to whatever path you getting for need controller-action

For more info check : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check make sure the only routes you have for accounts in `config/routes.rb` is:

```
resources :accounts
```

Your error message is stating that you are calling `profile_photo` on `account`, but `account` is a `nil` value, not an object that can receive a method call.

Ensure your `accounts_controller.rb` file includes these actions (i.e, methods):

```
class AccountsController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end

  def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```